# Create a new line replacing a section of text on sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Hi im trying a fast way to replicate a line on sublime text and a another line.
So basically i want to be able find a line that has got foobar in a css.

```
.foobar .text
```

I want to be able to keep the first line but also have another line with a new class that inherits the styles.

```
.foobar .text,
.durp .text
```

Is there a way to do this on sublime, where it will work on a large variety of content.

```
.foobar .text{}
.foobar .img{}
.foobar .cat{}
.foobar .dog{}
.foobar .button{}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. Please [edit] your post to add a complete example: What is in the file beforehand, what exactly you want to match and duplicate, and what you want the file to look like at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text supports [search and replace with regular expressions](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions). You can write a regular expression to find your first line and replace it with your first line and a second one based on the information you got from your regex.